# How find all positive integers $N_{i},k_{i},T_{i}$

Tags: number-theory

if $T_{i},k_{i},N_{i},i=1,2,3,4,5$ are positive integer numbers,and such
$$\begin{cases}
k_{1}T_{1}+k_{2}T_{2}+k_{3}T_{3}+k_{4}T_{4}+k_{5}T_{5}\le 35\\
N_{1}T_{1}+N_{2}T_{2}+N_{3}T_{3}+N_{4}T_{4}+N_{5}T_{5}\le 116\\
\dfrac{k_{1}}{N_{1}}<\dfrac{k_{2}}{N_{2}}<\dfrac{k_{3}}{N_{3}}<\dfrac{k_{4}}{N_{4}}<\dfrac{k_{5}}{N_{5}}
\end{cases}$$

find all $(T_{i},N_{i},k_{i})$

This problem is from :http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2558735370

My idea is to use an enumeration method. This subject has cleverly enumeration?
Thank you everyone

Comment: Did you leave out the condition $N_i\leq 3$ intentionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve it by computer using brute force method ! although it not the best thing to do it still more helpful and quicker way ... furthermore one can see that all $N_i,T_i,k_i\le35$ otherwise the first inequality can not hold ... so the brute force will be $35^3=42875$ iterations , you can simplify the inequalities and see if other methods do the job quicker ...